# Predict() function Output

Tags: r

I have established a regression model as:

```
model3 <- lm(log(datediff) ~ moviesclean$runtime +
    moviesclean$critics_score + moviesclean$critics_rating + 
    moviesclean$mpaa_rating, data = moviesclean)
```

I then defined the parameters for a specific observation as:

```
moonlight_predict <- data.frame(
    runtime = "111", 
    critics_rating = "Certified Fresh", 
    critics_score = "99", 
    mpaa_rating = "R", 
    data = moviesclean)
```

Now I am trying to predict the dependent variable for the specific observation using the regression model, `model3`, using the `predict()` function:

```
predict(model3, newdata = moonlight_predict, interval = "confidence", level = .95)
```

My question concerns the output of this `predict()` function.  The output is giving me 619 responses for fit, lwr and upr.  Why isn't the output just one response?  How do I get the one predicted value for the new observation that lies outside my dataframe?

Comment: You're attaching your entire original data `moviesclean` to `moonlight_predict`. So `predict` will return predictions for your specific observation *plus* all observations from the original dataset. Also, you don't need to write `moviesclean$runtime` etc. in `lm`, just `runtime` suffices since you provide the `data` argument. So `lm(log(datediff) ~ runtime + critics_score + ..., data = moviesclean)` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include your original data in `newdata`. The following will use your model to predict the response for one observation.

```
predict(
    model3,
    newdata = data.frame(
        runtime = "111",
        critics_rating = "Certified Fresh",
        critics_score = "99",
        mpaa_rating = "R"),
    interval = "confidence", level = .95)
```